# ruby sort an array alphabetically,unique and loop though 5 times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, view-helpers

I am retrieving elements from an array:

```
  - member_results.each do |member|
      = member
```

It returns something like this:

```
["John", "Jason", "Andy", "Zee", "Sandy", "Randy", "Grisham"]
```

I need to sort the array alphabetically, retrieve only the first five unique elements from the array. Can someone recommend me an efficient way to write a helper for this?

EDIT:
So based on the answer provided by squiguy this what I did:

```
member_results.map(&:downcase).sort.uniq.take(5)
```

That solves most of my problem. 
But when I am displaying those results I need them back to the original format.

```
For example the result could be grisHam, aNdy etc.
```

Comment: see answer below.  make sure to use parantheses for (result1 | result2).sort.uniq.first(5)

Comment: What do you expect back from this:
`["John", "Jason", "Andy", "Zee", "Sandy", "Randy", "Grisham","john"]`  If you want to keep original case, then you would have john twice,  otherwise you would have to pick one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My venture would be something like:

```
member_results.sort_by(&:downcase).uniq.take(5)
```

If you are using the union operator for two arrays, there is no need for `uniq`.

```
(a1 | a2).sort.take(5)
```

Comment: i tried that but that didnt work. Maybe because my array was a join of 2 arrays? member_results = results1 | results2

Comment: What didn't work? The join shouldn't affect anything, unless you did it after the call.

Comment: @Tilo Must have. Order matters, seems like you pointed that out. He didn't post it in his question so there is no way of knowing.

Comment: I figured out what the issue was. Some of the names were lowercase so it didnt sort them.

Comment: @newbie Oh a simple `.map(&:downcase)` should fix that if need be.

Comment: Thanks, Both @squiguy and Tilo. I can accept only one answer!

Comment: I guess I will give it to @squiguy for the downcase suggestion. But do I have to convert back to uppercase again when i display them! Because uppercase would convert all chars to uppercase

Comment: I guess what I mean is there a way I can downcase and sort but when I display it, it should be in whatever format the original string was.

Answer (score 1):

to get the sorted unique array:

```
member_results.sort.uniq
```

to loop over the first 5 unique members:

```
member_results.sort.uniq[0..4].each do |m|
 ... 
end
```

or:

```
member_results.sort.uniq.first(5).each do |m|
 ... 
end
```

or:

```
member_results.sort.uniq.take(5).each do |m|
 ... 
end
```

---

```
(result1 | result2).sort.uniq.first(5)
```

Comment: You don't need the uniq with the last one, the | will take care of it,

Comment: @ShawnBalestracci Not necessarily. He wants the end result to be unique too.

Comment: each array can have multiple copies inside it, e.g. if you would select the firstname of user records... The OP requested unique results

Comment: [Set Union (|) — Returns a new array by joining ary with other_ary, *excluding any duplicates* and preserving the order from the original array.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-7C)